# Can I bring back innerText of div in the textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am making my own project and I got stuck middle.

First, let me describe what I am trying to make.
you write something in the `textarea` tag and click the transfer button.
then on the left side, some div gonna pop up. it has 2divs inside.
The first one is not that important, it is just index literally.
The second one has a thing that you just wrote inside the `textarea` tag in the div.

It works totally okay until here. But the problem is when you want to get back text to the
`textarea`.

I wanted to add a function like this. when you click a div on the left(`.indexlayout`),
the text in the div(`.esssence` which its display is none;) is gonna be written in `textarea` tag, so you can review or re-write. But apparently, It doesn't work. I want to know what is problem and how to solve it. your help will be appreciated.
thx :)

```js
const transferButton = document.querySelector(".transfer");
const textArea = document.querySelector(".textarea");
const indexList = document.querySelector(".indexlist");

transferButton.addEventListener("click", transferDiary);

function transferDiary(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const indexLayout = document.createElement("div");
  indexLayout.classList.add("indexlayout");
  indexLayout.id = "indexlayout";

  const trashA = document.createElement("div");
  trashA.classList.add("trasha");
  trashA.innerText = `title`;
  const essence = document.createElement("div");
  essence.classList.add("essence");
  essence.innerText = textArea.value;

  indexLayout.appendChild(trashA);
  indexLayout.appendChild(essence);
  indexList.appendChild(indexLayout);

  const indexToButton = document.querySelector(".indexlayout");

  indexToButton.addEventListener("click", bringBackNote);
}

function bringBackNote(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const bringEssence = document.querySelector("essence");
  textArea.value = `${bringEssence.innerText}`;
}
```

```css
.frame {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50vw;
}

.indexlist {
  width: 20%;
}

.notepad {
  width: 80%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

.indexlayout {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.essence{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="frame">
     <div class="indexlist"></div>
     <form class="notepad"><button class="transfer">transfer</button><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="textarea"></textarea></form>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your javascript code such as below:

```
<script>
  const transferButton = document.querySelector(".transfer");
  const textArea = document.querySelector(".textarea");
  const indexList = document.querySelector(".indexlist");

  transferButton.addEventListener("click", transferDiary);
  var layout_no = 0; // add now
  function transferDiary(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const indexLayout = document.createElement("div");
    indexLayout.classList.add("indexlayout");
    indexLayout.id = "indexlayout-"+layout_no;

    const trashA = document.createElement("div");
    trashA.classList.add("trasha");
    trashA.innerText = `title`;
    const essence = document.createElement("div");
    essence.classList.add("essence");
    essence.innerText = textArea.value;

    indexLayout.appendChild(trashA);
    trashA.appendChild(essence);
    indexList.appendChild(indexLayout);

    // const indexToButton = document.querySelector(".indexlayout");
    const indexToButton = document.getElementById(
      "indexlayout-"+layout_no
    );
    indexToButton.addEventListener("click", bringBackNote);
    layout_no++;
  }

  function bringBackNote(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const bringEssence = e.target.getElementsByClassName("essence");
    textArea.value = bringEssence[0].innerHTML.replace(/\s?(<br\s?\/?>)\s?/g, "\r\n");
  }
</script>
```

Your fault is the making the elements have the same id - "essence".
So I fixed your code the ".essence" elements have the unique ids.
and `trashA` append to `indexLayout`. Finally, in the  `bringBackNote` function, the result of `document.querySelector(".essence")` is an array. So an error is occured in `textArea.value =` ${bringEssence.innerText}`;`.

Comment: hey thanks for your help. I think your solution is very clear and it is right.  But what I can't understand is 'replace(/\s?(<br\s?\/?>)\s?/g, "\r\n")' this part. I don't know what is this and maybe it is the reason why my console return 'test.js:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.bringBackNote' hmmm can you explain what is that please?

Comment: oh sorry I just read " trashA append to indexLayout" part hahaha and it works now. but I made that structure for some reason in my project do you know how I do this without change the structure of divs

Comment: as you can see, the content of the `.essence` contains <br>tags. These are for the new line(generated by entering you in textarea). you need to replace <br> tag to new line character. So I used replace(/\s?(<br\s?\/?>)\s?/g, "\r\n") function, in here, "/\s?(<br\s?\/?>)\s?/g" is the regExp of <br> html tag.

Answer (score 1):

Fisrt you need to add listener to `indexLayout` not `document.querySelector(".indexlayout");`

Then in your `bringBackNote` event you have to use `e.target.parentElement.children[1].innerText`. Because you need the inner text of tag that you click on it not all tag that has `essence` class.

You can make `e.target.parentElement.children[1]` better by finding `essence` class in `e.target.parentElement` but in your code we are sure second child of `indexLayout` always is that has `essence` class.

```js
const transferButton = document.querySelector(".transfer");
const textArea = document.querySelector(".textarea");
const indexList = document.querySelector(".indexlist");

transferButton.addEventListener("click", transferDiary);

function transferDiary(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const indexLayout = document.createElement("div");
  indexLayout.classList.add("indexlayout");
  indexLayout.id = "indexlayout";

  const trashA = document.createElement("div");
  trashA.classList.add("trasha");
  trashA.innerText = `title`;
  const essence = document.createElement("div");
  essence.classList.add("essence");
  essence.innerText = textArea.value;

  indexLayout.appendChild(trashA);
  indexLayout.appendChild(essence);
  indexList.appendChild(indexLayout);

  const indexToButton = document.querySelector(".indexlayout");

  indexLayout.addEventListener("click", bringBackNote);
}

function bringBackNote(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //const bringEssence = document.querySelector(".essence");
  textArea.value = `${e.target.parentElement.children[1].innerText}`;;
}
```

```css
.frame {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50vw;
}

.indexlist {
  width: 20%;
}

.notepad {
  width: 80%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

.indexlayout {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.essence{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
     <div class="indexlist"></div>
     <form class="notepad"><button class="transfer">transfer</button><textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="textarea"></textarea></form>
   </div>
```

Comment: thx now it bring back my note when i clicked it haha but problem is, as you mentioned, I have to change 'document.querySelector(".indexlayout");'

Comment: this one into other way haha because it only effects on first div in indexlist haha